# C++ class question to set point in class PLEASE

Tags: c++, class, point, segment

> 1. Please design a class Point represent a point on plane coordinates.
> 2. Give this class two private data member x and y represent the
>    location of the point, x and y are float type.
> 3. Create a default constructor to set x and y to 0.
> 4. Create a constructor with two float parameter to set x and y.
> 5. Create a public function member printPoint to display as the format
>    like "(x, y)"
> 6. Create public function member getX, setX, getY, setY to access the
>    data member x and y.
> 7. Create a public function member getDistance with one Point type
>    parameter, return a float type value represent the distance of two
>    point.
> 8. Please design a class Segment represent a segment on plane
>    coordinates.
> 9. Give this class two private data member point1 and point2 represent
>    the endpoint of this segment.
> 10. Create a default constructor to set the both endpoint to (0, 0).
> 11. Create a constructor with two Point object as parameter to set two
>     endpoint.
> 12. Implement the following function member
>
> float getLength(); //No parameter, return the length of the segment.

I don't know how to do the 10th, 11th, and 12th step.
This is my code.
I need somebody to teach me, thanks!!!

```
#include <math.h>
class Point
{
  public:
    Point()
    {
      x = y = 0;
    }
    Point(float x1, float y1)
    {
      x = x1;
      y = y1;
    }
    void setX(float X)
    {
      x = X;
    }  
    float getX() 
    {
      return x;
    } 
    void setY(float Y)
    {
      y = Y;  
    }  
    float getY() 
    {
      return y;
    }  
    void printPoint()
    {
      std::cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")";
    }
    float getDistance(Point p2)
    {
      return sqrt(pow(getX() - p2.getX(), 2) + pow(getY() - p2.getY(), 2));
    }
  private:
    float x;
    float y;
};
class Segment : public Point
{
  public:
    Segment()
    {
      point1 = {};
      point2 = {};
    }
    Segment(Point pt1, Point pt2)
    {
      point1 = pt1;
      point2 = pt2;
    }
    float getLength()
    {
      return sqrt(pow(point1.getX() - point2.getX(), 2) + pow(point1.getY() - point2.getY(), 2));
    }
  private:
    Point point1;
    Point point2;
};
```

Comment: why you cannot do them? Do you know what a default constructor is? Actually it looks like you already did 10)

Comment: _"I don't know how to do the 10th, 11th, and 12th step."_ - but, you already did them, no? What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I uploaded the onlinejudge is a wrong answer.

Comment: "wrong answer" is not sufficient to explain what is wrong with your code

Comment: @d901203: What problem are you trying to solve? Surely, an online judge is not testing your class function. What is your main function supposed to do? As I said in my answer, consider changing floats to doubles

Comment: This question would be better if you explain what you tried, what you expected, and what you got.

Comment: i tried to change float to double, but it still display wrong answer. i tried my best to do this......

Comment: @d901203 You did and your code looks correct. Maybe you can get your hands on some test cases or write your own unit tests to verify the correctness of yoru code.

Comment: @d901203: Did you change the types of the members as well? Changing the return type of get_length might not be enough

Comment: @d901203: You also conveniently forgot to reply to the main part of my quesion: i.e. what is the actual problem that the online jugde is checking your solution for? What is the specification of input and output?

Comment: i got the problom

Comment: the pow function in this question isn't used

Answer (score 2):

You have already implemented 10, 11, and 12.

```
Segment()
{
  point1 = {};
  point2 = {};
}
Segment(Point pt1, Point pt2)
{
  point1 = pt1;
  point2 = pt2;
}
```

This is the implementation of 10 and 11. I would use the constructor initializer list for initialization though:

```
Segment() = default;
Segment(const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2)
    :point1(pt1), point2(pt2) 
{

}
```

12 is implemented here:

```
float getLength()
{
  return sqrt(pow(point1.getX() - point2.getX(), 2) + pow(point1.getY() - point2.getY(), 2));
}
```

This function is NOT const-correct. You should make it const. I'd write it as follows:

```
float getLength() const
{
    const float dx = point1.getX() - point2.getX();
    const float dy = point1.getY() - point2.getY();
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

If you are getting errors  by a auto-checking software, such as ejudge, consider changing float to double as the wrong answer may well be due to lack of required precision